# How do you render a Twig template in a subdirectory without explicitly adding it to the paths?

Tags: php, twig

I am using PHP Twig's Filesystem loader, my path is defined as "views/"

In views/ are several subdirectories: path1/ path2/ and path3/

Is there a way, without having to define the paths explicitly, to render templates in these subdirectories? I tried `$twig->render("path1/template1", $scope);` however it cannot find "path1/template1" when searching for the template.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with `define the paths explicitly`? If you configure `twig` correctly and set `views/` as the view folder you should need to be able to do it like : `$twig->render('directory1/view.html');` and for subdirectories `$twig->render('directory1/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/list.html');`

Comment: Aha you are right @DarkBee!

It was correctly defined, however I was using a custom error handler and Twig's PHP library uses error suppression to include a file that doesn't exist that was triggering the custom error handler.